# Как реализовать локализацию сайта

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Использую Express, запускаю на нем сервер.
У меня есть парочку страниц, на которых я хочу сделать локализацию.

На данный момент я это хочу сделать с помощью `get` параметра `lang=en` / `lang=ru`, но немного не понимаю как это реализовать в коде.
Я нашел пакет `express-request-language`, с помощью него, я узнаю локализацию, как я понимаю браузера:

```js
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(requestLanguage(
{
    languages: ['en-US', 'ru-RU'],
    cookie:
    {
        name: 'language',
        options: { maxAge: 24*3600*1000 },
        url: '/languages/{language}'
    }
}));
```

... и записываю его в куки.

Дальше в нашем 'роуте', мы можем узнать локаль с помощью `req.language.substr(0, 2) // -> en`, но вот тут начинается интересное.
Нужно чтобы если `get` параметром не было передано языка (`?lang=en`), то он устанавливался из кукиксов в url.

Что мне нужно сделать? Redirect на ту же ссылку, но добавить `get` параметр `lang`? Или как лучше?

Так же сделать проверку на язык указанные в get параметром, разрешен ли он.
Допустим это будет массив языков `const langAccess = ['en', 'ru'];`.

### Дополнительный вопрос по `express-request-language`:

Какую он локаль установит, если будет допустим `de`? Если я правильно понимаю, то в `languages` мы указали список 'разрешенных' локалей, но можно как-то установить по стандарту допустим `ru`? Я где-то мельком замечал, что по стандарту стоит `en-US`, это так? И где это можно проверить?

---

*(Мне кажется, что в целом вопрос плохо получилось сформулировать, но надеюсь на ваше понимание.)*

---

На данный момент я реализовал что-то вроде этого:

```js
const langAccess = ['en', 'ru'];

// ...

// Rust gene
rustGeneRouter.use('/rust_gene', (req, res, next) =>
{
    let langGet = req.query.lang; // Получаем get параметр - lang
    let langCookie = req.language?.substr(0, 2); // Получаем lang из кукиксов

    let lang = langAccess.find(lang => lang == langGet) || langAccess.find(lang => lang == langCookie) || 'en';

    if (langGet != lang)
    {
        let newSeach = new URLSearchParams(req._parsedUrl.search);
            newSeach.set('lang', lang);

        res.redirect(`?${newSeach.toString()}`);
    }
    else
    {
        next();
    }
});

rustGeneRouter.use('/rust_gene', (req, res) =>
{
    res.send(`Lang 'rust gene' page: ${req.query.lang}`);
})

app.get('/rust_gene', rustGeneRouter);

// Main
app.use('/', (req, res, next) =>
{
    let langGet = req.query.lang; // Получаем get параметр - lang
    let langCookie = req.language?.substr(0, 2); // Получаем lang из кукиксов

    let lang = langAccess.find(lang => lang == langGet) || langAccess.find(lang => lang == langCookie) || 'en';

    if (langGet != lang)
    {
        let newSeach = new URLSearchParams(req._parsedUrl.search);
            newSeach.set('lang', lang);

        res.redirect(`?${newSeach.toString()}`);
    }
    else
    {
        next();
    }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) =>
{
    res.status(404).render(path.join(__dirname, 'renderer', 'index.ejs'), {lang: req.query.lang});
});

app.get('/pageNotFound', (req, res) =>
{
    res.status(404).render(path.join(__dirname, 'renderer', 'pageNotFound.ejs'), {lang: req.query.lang});
});


// Error 404
app.use((req, res) =>
{
    res.redirect('/pageNotFound')
});
```

... и оно вроде работает как нужно.
`/?lang=de` перемемещает на `/?lang=en`, `/` перемещает на `/?lang=en`, `/?lang=ru` ничего не делает.
Так же есть повторение кода, что не очень нравится, да и в целом все, не очень.

---

Может вообще лучше использовать для этих целей параметры, а не get параметры?

```js
app.get("/:lang", ...)
```

Comment: Вам будет полезно узнать про модуль про `i18next` https://lokalise.com/blog/node-js-i18n-express-js-localization/

Comment: Как-то все слишком мудренно выглядит, возможно это и хороший вариант для большого приложения, но даже не знаю.. Из статейки лишь увидел как лучше роуты делать.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать спарсить `request.headers['accept-language']`.

И генерируйте страницу с учетом языка.